# How to have maven build my project with all the dependencies in a separte folder, ready to package?

Tags: netbeans, maven

How do I create a package of a Maven project that contains the jar with my classes, plus a directory like "lib" with all the needed dependencies? I'm using netbeans ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can copy required libs into a folder using [Maven dependency plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/) [copy-dependencies goal](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/copying-project-dependencies.html).

In addition to that you can use [Maven assembly plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/) to create an archive containing your jar and this lib folder.